# How to create a JSON object using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

If I have the following JSON Payload how can I code it using Javascript?

{"releaseTitle":"Testing with the Advanced Fields",
"variables":{"jm_key_value_map":{"key2":"value2","name":"jhm"},"jm_list":["item1","item1","item3"],"jm_set":["item1","item1","item3"],"autoStart":"true"}}

In postman I can use this payload in a post api to create a record. However I now need to code it using Javascript in the integration that I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, JSON objects are, well, Javascript objects..

You could simply write something like this:

```
let jsonObject = {
  releaseTitle:"Testing with the Advanced Fields", 
  variables: {
    jm_key_value_map: {
      key2: "value2", 
      name: "jhm"
    },
    jm_list: ["item1", "item1", "item3"],
    jm_set: ["item1", "item1", "item3"],
    autoStart: "true"
  }
};
```

You can also create the same object dynamically, adding one property at a time, like so:

```
let jsonObject = {};
jsonObject.releaseTitle = "Testing with the Advanced Fields";
jsonObject.variables = {};
jsonObject.variables.jm_key_value_map = {};
jsonObject.variables.jm_key_value_map.key2 = "value2";
jsonObject.variables.jm_key_value_map.name = "jhm";
jsonObject.variables.jm_list = ["item1", "item1", "item3"];
jsonObject.variables.jm_set = ["item1", "item1", "item3"];
jsonObject.variables.autoStart = "true";
```

And you can also mix & match, something like this:

```
let jsonObject = {};
jsonObject["releaseTitle"] = "Testing with the Advanced Fields";
jsonObject.variables = {
  jm_key_value_map: {
    key2: "value2", 
    name:"jhm"
  },
  jm_list: ["item1", "item1", "item3"],
  jm_set: ["item1", "item1", "item3"],
  autoStart: "true"
};
```

This is because the JSON data format was inspired by Javascript. It's even in the name (JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation). Read more: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Thanks Mike, I went for #2 and it works!

Comment: Glad it worked. Sorry your question got closed. Sometimes people forget that even "simple" things may not be obvious to beginners..